# Attaching css to blocks

Tags: 7, blocks

Why do we use **$block['content']** while attaching css or js files to block ?

```
$block['content']['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module',
                                          'mymodule' . '/mymodule.css');
```

What does that 'content' mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A block array has a 'subject' and 'content' key, it's just a convention. See [`hook_block_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) for details:

> **Return value**
>
> Either an empty array so the block will not be shown or an array containing the following elements:
>
> - subject: The default localized title of the block. If the block does not have a default title, this should be set to NULL.
> - content: The content of the block's body. This may be a renderable array (preferable) or a string containing rendered HTML content. If the content is empty the block will not be shown.